# Correct tense for "I wish I had worn socks today"

Tags: grammar, tenses

I had an argument in the office today, about structuring something I said about not wearing socks.
I said the first of the four lines below, then everyone had their input.  All the arguing gave three more options. What is the correct way to say this?

> I wish I had worn socks today.
>   I wish I'd worn socks today.
>   I wish I'd had worn socks today.
>   I wish I'd have had worn socks today.

Comment: I think this question is too localized to be useful.  It's not clear what part you have a question about.  Of the examples, the first two are equivalent and correct (one just uses a contraction) and the others are incorrect.

Comment: I think it's general reference, apart from the totally pointless issue about whether it's "correct tense" to contract **I had** into **I'd**.

Comment: @C.Johns: Out of curiosity, where is your office located, and what language(s) is(are) natively spoken by you and your officemates?

Comment: @C .Johns, out of curiosity as well, do you mean to say that you wear shoes without socks sometimes?

Comment: Sorry, to rain on the party, but where's: I wish I've worn socks today? What's interesting to me and therefore is quasi-proof these are not AmE speakers is the absence of the horrible sounding: I wish I would have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers 1 and 2 are identical (apart from *I had* being contracted) and are **correct**.

The rest of them are not.

Also note that a *that* has been elided from all of them. The full sentence would be:

> I wish *that* I had worn socks today.

Comment: I would call the tense in number 3 Past Past Perfect, and the tense in 4 Future Perfect in the Past Past... thank God these do not exist :)

Comment: ha! yes I am no english scolar but find the above very funny. Thank you for the answer Jim, I now have office superiority for the day.