# was or were in Subjunctive Mood

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, subjunctive-mood, irrealis-were

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)
>   [Which is correct: “what if there was” or “what if there were”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/which-is-correct-what-if-there-was-or-what-if-there-were)

Which of following sentences is formed properly? Why?

> Although Reza has a successful career as a lawyer, he still wishes he
>   **was** a rock musician.

or

> Although Reza has a successful career as a lawyer, he still wishes he
>   **were** a rock musician.

Comment: This has been covered elsewhere, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Actually, Barrie, I don't find them the same.  The question is whether *wish* still takes a verb in the past subjunctive. This is rather different from asking about a hypothetical *if* clause, don't you think?

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80723/2085) is the one that should not have been closed to the "what if" question, because that isn't what these are. However, also related are: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21204/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63121/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/37536/2085 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/60200/2085 and probably many more. So ok, it is probably a dupe, but just not of the one that Barrie listed it as a dupe of.

Comment: @tchrist: OK. It's just that whenever I see anything about _wish_ and _were_ my eyes glaze over, and I want to direct the question elsewhere as soon as possible.

Comment: @kiamlaluno No, that is the wrong dupe. That is the if-subjunctive, not the wish-subjunctive.

Comment: @tchrist The first question has been closed as duplicate of the second question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Sorry, I must be slow today, because I don't understand what you mean. [Your own possible dupe](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/660/2085) does not apply here. [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21204/2085) is the operative dupe here, don't you think?

Comment: @tchrist _Which is correct: "what if there was" or "what if there were"?_ is closed as duplicate of _"If I was" or "If I were". Which is more common, and which is correct?_ In such cases, I prefer to vote to close as duplicate of the question that is still not closed, not as duplicate of a question that is then a duplicate of another question. It is just a matter of preferences.

Answer (score 5):

I would use ***were***, because *wish* is one of those very rare verbs that still takes the subjunctive mood for most speakers.  This was a big deal when once upon a time the original Oscar Meyer weiner song came out with the lyrics

> *Oh, I wish I **was** an Oscar Mayer weiner,
>  that is what I'd truly like to be,
>  'cause if I were an Oscar Mayer weiner, 
> everyone would be in love with me!*

And there was a big write-in campaign to make them "fix" to its current rendering:

> *Oh, I wish I **were** an Oscar Mayer weiner,
>  that is what I'd truly like to be,
>  'cause if I were an Oscar Mayer weiner, 
> everyone would be in love with me!*

*Wish* is a pretty common verb in English, and it takes past subjunctive for those who still maintain that distinction for the hypothetical, contrary-to-reality case.

Comment: No one maintains the distinction for persons other than the first and third singular.

Comment: One must admit that the internal rhyme of the first line makes the "fix" much more catchy, regardless of its grammatical status.